# Logging- Python - How to apply my formatter ? That doesn't work

Tags: python, python-logging

I am using the library logging for my python project and I am trying to separate the logging errors and logging info. Errors and Info are separated, that works.

But the formater is not considered for both of them.
Here is my code. I hope someone already had this issue.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('get_data_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)  

stderr_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stderr_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
stderr_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
logger.addHandler(stderr_handler)
```

The result is :

```
ERROR:root:Empty DataFrame
```

That doesn't look like my formatter

I define stdout and stderr in a service file like this :

```
StandardOutput=append:/dir/output.txt
StandardError=append:/dir/outputError.txt
```

Comment: You are not logging to the logger `get_data_logger`. Loggers work by name, which should usually be the `__name__` of the module. And on the top level there's the root logger.

Comment: I found the mistake. 
My previous code used BasicConfig of logging to manage the logs. But then I tried to used a logger to separate errors from info. 


So I needed to change the logs message from : 
logging.info("message")
to 
logger.info("message")